# Get Sharepoint token in Excel add-in

Tags: office-js

Our Excel Add-in needs an OAUTH token for some functions which call the SharePoint REST API.

The add-in uses the Ribbon Commands and we don't have a task pane. We have the following code to obtain the token from other projects:

```js
var dhi = dhi || {};
dhi.adal = (function (mod) {

    var settings = {
        clientId: "xxxyyyyzzzz",
        url: "https://company.sharepoint.com"
    };


    mod.getToken = function () {

        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        //fix origin for IE
        if (!window.location.origin) {
            window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
        }

        var configOptions = {
            clientId: settings.clientId,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        }

        window.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(configOptions);

        var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
        authContext.handleWindowCallback();

        var user = authContext.getCachedUser();

        if (!user) {
            authContext.login();

        } else {

            var cachedToken = authContext.getCachedToken(user.profile.aud);
            if (!cachedToken) {
                authContext.login();
            } else {


                var url = settings.url;

                var tok = authContext.acquireToken(url, function (error, token) {
                    console.log(error);
                    if (token != null) {
                        console.log(token);
                        sharedtoken = token;
                        dfd.resolve(token);
                    } else {
                        if (cachedToken != "" && cachedToken != null && cachedToken != undefined) {
                            dfd.resolve(cachedToken);
                        } else {
                            dfd.reject("Unable to obtain token. Please contact hotline@dhigroup.com with the following error : " + error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return dfd.promise();
    }
    return mod;
})(dhi.adal || {});
```

and in the `functions.js` file (where the handlers of ribbon buttons are defined) we call this initialization:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

        dhi.adal.getToken.then(
            function (token) {
                sharedtoken = token;
                Office.initialize = function (reason) {

                    // some code here

                }
            },
            function (error) {
                app.showNotification("Problem occured", error);
            });
    });
})();
```

We are facing following problems:

1) If the token is already cached it works. However, when it needs to call `authContext.login()`, it hangs (no message nowhere). We believe doesn't know  where to display the login dialog (in the very first version of this add-in we used a task pane and it displayed the login page there, however, for several reasons we need to use the commands.

2) We must call it before the `Office.initialize` is called, otherwise it doesn't work ( I tried to put `getToken` only to the functions needing it but without success)- no idea why. This has a side effect, that we must call `getToken()` always, also for button actions, when no token is needed

3) I tried to create a dialog to obtain the token, but there are some other issues - some problems in `adal.js`...

So, I'd like to ask - is there any straightforward way how to obtain a SharePoint token from Active directory in Office.jas

If there was some sample, it would help us a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built in method for obtaining a token for SharePoint.

As for opening an authentication dialog, you should use the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#using-the-dialog-apis-in-an-authentication-flow) for this. There is a sample PowerPoint Add-in that uses the Dialog API to authenticate against Graph: [PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart). The principals and components used here should translate easily to Excel and SharePoint.

For an authentication library, I'd recommend taking a look at [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).

You also need to ensure your functions file assigns `Office.initialize` immediately on page load. This isn't an outbound call to a init function, it is a property you're assigning an init function too. Office will call this method automatically and if you haven't assigned a function it will result in errors.